# Cant api connection doesnt work on production react native

Tags: reactjs, api, react-native, express, redux

Before building the react native app to production, I was able to log in and I could get error messages for any errors but after building to apk, I ran the app on my android phone but It didn't work.

I am fetching the user login like this;

```
import { userTypes } from '../../types';
const { USER_LOGIN } = userTypes;

const SERVER_URL = "http://localhost:8080/api/v1";

const loginAction = (userdata) => dispatch => {
    fetch(`${SERVER_URL}/auth/signin`,{
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'content-type' : 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(userdata)
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data =>(
        dispatch({
        type: USER_LOGIN,
        payload: data
    })))
}

export {
    loginAction
};
```

Is there a proper way to use api connections both on development and production.

Comment: Did you give the apk permissions to use the internet?

Comment: @ApplePearPerson you meant this `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` I have it already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are using android 9. If it's the case try with this:

Add in your main **AndroidManifest.xml**

```xml
<manifest xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"> 
    <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" tools:targetApi="28">                                         </application>  
</manifest>
```